# Ask the user for the starting value. Set up the output to display 10 values per line and then start a new line

Tags: java, while-loop

```
public class StayPositive {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Counting down..");
    int i = 59;
    while (i >= 0) {
      System.out.println(i);
      i--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am voting to close, you need to include the code in your question (not an image). If you only want 10 items per line then use a `for` or `while` that runs 10 times and to print on the same line read the JavaDoc: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html use `print(...)` not `println(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Scanner` to take user input. And use `%` function to change the liner after every 10 numbers:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Give a number: ");
    int givenNumber = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());

    for(int i = givenNumber, j=1 ; i>=0 ; i--, j++) {
      if(j%10 == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
      } else {
        System.out.print(i);;
      }
    }
  }
```

**Input :** 59

**Output :**

```
59585756555453525150
49484746454443424140
39383736353433323130
29282726252423222120
19181716151413121110
9876543210
```